# MS Access - Resetting Combo Box within a Subform

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I'm having an issue with a control I've built into a dashboard used by our medical credentialing staff.The control is a combobox in a contracting subform that is within a demographic form, the primary key in the demographic form is ProviderId, this is also the foreign key in the contracting table in this relationship.

The combobox is built to allow the association of a ProviderId (an identifier for medical staff) and TINLevelEntityId (an identifier for practices) where there is a documented association already established between the provider and the practice in a junction table that serves that purpose.

I'm able to restrict the values that populate in the combo box appropriately by using criteria in the underlying query that only returns values where the ProviderId in the controls row source is equivelant to the ProviderId in the enclosing form. My issue is that when I navigate to a new record the control does not reset and the values that appeared for the first provider continue to reappear for all other providers. I've tried using the requery command in an after update event but it doesn't seem to want to work. I've tried a few different approaches and am stumped. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: You used `Requery` for subform or for combobox? Requery for combobox should work. Try manually requery the field first - set focus on combobox and press F5

Comment: Manual requery does work. I do have the requery set for the combobox, is there something I'm likely messing up with the requery macro for the combobox?

Comment: Looks like. Which code do you use for combobox requery?

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to use refresh the subform in which the combobox was located so I put a refresh macro to trigger on entering the form. Thank you for the direction, wasn't aware of manual or macro based refresh, still learning.